# Passing data to a method

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I am working on a smart contract that take a data from each node to be stored in the blockchain

What is the best data structure to pass it as a method parameter?. I have done a string but it doesn't work if I pass a long string which contains some special character.

For example, I have the following code:

```
function push (String str)
{
.....
}

// invoking the method 
push("temp-temp,1234*cent,skgvxcj12497sdf7485t70gsbvw4987ety");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with passing such a string.
Tried the following on Remix and it does work:

```
contract Test {

    string public data;

    function push (string str)
    {
        data = str;
    }

    function pushTheString(){
        push("temp-temp,1234*cent,skgvxcj12497sdf7485t70gsbvw4987ety");
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I try it, EV exception appears, I will try it again and try to detect where the error is, Cheers

Comment: @sheemar Operations with strings may require large amounts of gas, be sure you have send enough gas with the transaction.